# CommunityToolkit.Maui.Storage.FileSaver does not work when<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>

Tags: maui, maui-windows

I am building the .netMaui app. I have the following settings for the project

```
<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
```

and launchsetting.json as below

```
{
"profiles": {
"Windows Machine": {
"commandName": "Project",
"nativeDebugging": false
}
```

}
}

with the above setting when I try to use FileSaver for the SaveAs file feature it fails with the following error.

{FileSaverResult { FilePath = , Exception = System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Storage.FileSaverImplementation.InternalSaveAsync(String initialPath, String fileName, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core/Essentials/FileSaver/FileSaverImplementation.windows.cs:line 31
at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Storage.FileSaverImplementation.InternalSaveAsync(String initialPath, String fileName, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core/Essentials/FileSaver/FileSaverImplementation.windows.cs:line 38
at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Storage.FileSaverImplementation.SaveAsync(String fileName, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core/Essentials/FileSaver/FileSaverImplementation.shared.cs:line 26, IsSuccessful = False }}

And Filesaver works fine when I use MSIX package

Comment: Please submit a bug for this on the repo, thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in my project. I copied your steps and used the `FileSaver.Default.SaveAsync()`. It worked well.

Comment: The issue is at the runtime. when you launch the app and try to click on SaveAs to get the save file the dialog does not open and you will see the exception in the code..  Can you please try this?

Comment: It appears a bug. You can report this on the github.